# ¿Cómo obtener en una variable el código de retorno de una ejecución de un comando o funcion?

Tags: bash, shell

Tengo un script, que llama a la ejecución de otro script (que yo no he creado) y quiero recoger en una variable el código de retorno que devuelve el segundo script (ya sea mediante exit o f_control) al que estoy llamando desde el mío.

```
${CK_PATH_SCRT}/kids5mail_cct.sh "${ENTORNO}" "${PERFIL}" "${NOMBRE_FICHERO}"
CODRET=?

echo $CODRET
```

Lo quiero almacenar en la variable CODRET, pero no se si se hace como indico arriba o con `CODRET=$?`

Algunas partes de como devuelve valores el script **kids5mail_cct.sh** son:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Muestra por pantalla la forma de utilizar el script.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
                echo " USO: ${0} <Entorno> <Perfil> <Fichero Mail>"
                echo
                echo " - Entorno: Entorno en que se ejecuta"
                echo " - Perfil: Perfil de ejecucion"
                echo " - Fichero Mail: Contenido Mail"
                echo "Se han recibido $# parametros de entrada:"
                I=1

                while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
                                echo "Parametro ${I}: $1"
                                shift
                                let I=I+1
                done

                exit 2
else
                echo "PARAMETROS CORRECTOS"
fi


#Parameters
ENTORNO=${1}
PERFIL=${2}
MAIL_FILE=${3}


#se comprueba que el parametro 3, contenido del mail, no este vacio
if [ ! -s ${CK_PATH_TMP}/${MAIL_FILE} ]
        then
        echo "CODRET=${CODRET}: ERROR FICHERO SIN CONTENIDO ${CK_PATH_TMP}/${MAIL_FILE}"
    echo "FINAL DE LA EJECUCION DEL SCRIPT"
    exit 9
fi
```

Una de las funciones que contiene, en este caso para comprobar que el perfil es correcto

```
function parse_profile_file {
        PERFIL_CORREO="${1}"
        if [ $(grep "^${PERFIL_CORREO}\|" ${FICHERO_PERFILES}|wc -l) -eq 0 ] || [ $(grep "^${PERFIL_CORREO}\|" ${FICHERO_PERFILES}|awk -F"|" '{print NF}') -ne 4 ]
                        then
                        f_tee "Perfil o parametros incorrectos"
                        f_control 1
        fi
        f_log "Perfil OK"       
        set -A PARAMS_CORREO $(grep "^${PERFIL_CORREO}|" ${FICHERO_PERFILES} | sed -e 's/\|/ /g' -e "s/$PERFIL_CORREO//")


        echo ${PARAMS_CORREO[@]}
}

function get_param{...}

function send_mail{...}

# MAIN

# Se procesa el fichero de perfiles para extraer los parametros del correo que se quiere enviar
parse_profile_file ${PERFIL}

# Se obtiene el asunto
...

# Se obtiene el correo
...

# ${PARAMS_CORREO[0]} -> FROM
# ${PARAMS_CORREO[1]} -> TO
# ${PARAMS_CORREO[3]} -> ASUNTO
# ${PARAMS_CORREO[4]} -> CUERPO
# ${PARAMS_CORREO[5]} -> ADJUNTO/NO

# Se envia el correo
send_mail "${PARAMS_CORREO[0]}" "${PARAMS_CORREO[1]}" "${PARAMS_CORREO[3]}" "${PARAMS_CORREO[4]}" "${PARAMS_CORREO[5]}"

f_tee "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
f_tee "Proceso finalizado "
f_tee "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Aquí termina. Esto es todo lo que podría conseguir del código del kids5mail_cct. No tengo acceso a las funciones `send_mail` ni `get_param` ni algunas partes intermedias del código.

¿Cuál sería la forma correcta?

Comment: nótese de todos modos que `$?` devuelve el estado de la ejecución anterior. 0 si fue correcta, otro número si no lo fue. Si lo que quieres recoger es el valor que devuelve un comando, usa `var=$(comando)`.

Comment: @fedorqui gracias por tu respuesta. Ahora me vuelve la siguiente duda: el script kids5mail_cct devuelve valores de dos formas, mediante exit valor, y mediante f_control valor. Si lo que quiero es recoger ese valor devuelto, entonces ¿qué método sería el correcto? Gracias

Comment: Para responderte con conocimiento de causa debería ver cómo has definido el script kids5mail_cct. Dale a [edit] y añade una parte representativa de este para que pueda replicarlo en mi ordenador y sugerir maneras.

Comment: @fedorqui editado, aunque el script kids5mail_cct no lo he creado yo, te paso algunas de las partes que contiene donde se muestran los valores devuletos.

Comment: De acuerdo. De todos modos, no veo dónde llamas _parse_profile_file_ ni si es relevante en todo esto. Con un [mcve] hay más que suficiente, no hace falta entrar en detalles. Entiendo que lo que quieres recoger es el `exit 2`, `exit 9`, etc, ¿verdad?

Comment: Exacto, lo que quiero es recoger el exit 2 o el exit 9, o lo que parece que devuelve f_control 1. He añadido algo más de código de lo que he podido tener acceso. Las partes con ... es lo que no recuerdo o no sé.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu script debe recuperar el valor de retorno con `CODRET=$?`, la estructura debe ser algo similar a:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "ejecutando script_2"

sh script_2.sh    #Aquí la ejecución del script kids5mail_cct.sh
CODRET=$?         #Recuperar el valor de retorno del script

echo "$CODRET"    #Imprimir el valor de retorno
```

Suponiendo que el script ***kids5mail_cct.sh*** retorne un 2, la ejecución debe mostrar algo como:

```
$ sh script_1.sh 
salida regular script kids5mail_cct.sh
ejecutando script_2
2
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, todo aclarado.

Answer (score 2):

Es una pena pero en Bash no existe la funcionalidad típica de `return` que tantos otros lenguajes tienen para devolver un valor de una función a otra, o incluso entre ficheros.

No me gusta la falta de esta funcionalidad, pero supongo que tiene su expicación. Uno de sus motivos es que las variables no son locales (a menos que se las defina explícitamente así), sino que tienen un ámbito que permite cambiarlas dentro de funciones:

```
$ cat f3.sh
#!/bin/bash

hola () {
   echo "en la función hola, r: $r"
   r=23
}

r=4
echo "en la función principal, r: $r"
hola
echo "tras llamar a hola, en la función principal, r: $r"
```

Ejecutamos el script:

```
$ bash f3.sh 
en la función principal, r: 4
en la función hola, r: 4
tras llamar a hola, en la función principal, r: 23
```

Dicho lo cual, tenemos dos soluciones para recoger los valores lanzados desde funciones u otros scripts:

- usar `exit`
- usar `echo` - la que yo prefiero

## Usar `exit`

Cuando se lanza un comando en Bash, este se intenta ejecutar. Dependiendo de su éxito, devuelve un estado. Si la ejecución fue correcta, devuelve `0`; si no, otro número distinto.

Este valor se guarda en `$?`:

De [Bash Reference Manual → 3.4.2 Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

> **$?** Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

Es decir:

> **$?** Expande al estado de salida de la pipeline más recientemente ejecutada en primer plano.

```
$ touch fichero
$ ls fichero
fichero
$ echo $?
0

$ ls asdfasd
ls: cannot access 'asdfasd': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
```

Esto resulta útil por ejemplo para validar si un `tar` se ejecutó correctamente o similar y nos permite hacer short-circuits del tipo:

```
$ ls asdfasd && echo "existe" || echo "no existe"
ls: cannot access 'asdfasd': No such file or directory
no existe

$ touch fichero
$ ls fichero && echo "existe" || echo "no existe"
fichero
existe
```

Volviendo al caso que nos incumbe, esto permite que lances un script y al final del todo generes un `exit` con algún número que luego recoges en el script que lo lanza:

```
$ cat f1.sh 
#!/bin/bash

exit 23

$ cat f2.sh 
#!/bin/bash

r=$(bash f1.sh)
echo "salida del anterior script: $?"
echo "recibí: $r"
```

Ejecutemos:

```
$ bash f2.sh 
salida del anterior script: 23
recibí:
```

Vale, funciona, si bien tiene el problema de que estamos usando `exit` para devolver cosas, cuando en general es una especie de "flag" para indicar si se pudo ejecutar bien o no.

## Usar `echo`

Generalmente si queremos devolver algo utilizamos `echo`:

```
$ cat f1.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "hola"
exit 23
$ cat f2.sh 
#!/bin/bash

r=$(bash f1.sh)
echo "salida del anterior script: $?"
echo "recibí: $r"
```

Ejecutemos:

```
$ bash f2.sh 
salida del anterior script: 23
recibí: hola
```

Básicamente, como ves, consiste en ir añadiendo `echo`s (o `printf` si quieres) pues su salida será recogida por el script que lo llame utilizando la sintaxis `variable=$(comando)` característica de Bash.

A mí me gusta más esta opción y es la que recomiendo.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, me has aclarado muchos conceptos que tenía mezclados. Explicación perfecta. Gracias @fedorqui